# Change window title dynamically in libGDX

Tags: libgdx, desktop

How can I change window title during my game? I can't find any method for that. For example I want to show how many points I scored in title bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this :

```
Gdx.graphics.setTitle(""+yourScore);
```

Good luck !